# $((X_{n}, X_{n+1}, \cdots, X_{n+k}))_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ markov chain implies $(X_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ markov chain?

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

Let $(\mathcal{F}_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a filtration of a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$, $E$ be a countable set and for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $X_{n}$ be a random variable from $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ to $(E, \mathcal{P}(E))$. Fix an integer $k \geq 1$.

For every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, denote $X_{n}^{(k)} := (X_{n}, X_{n+1}, \cdots, X_{n+k})$. Suppose that $(X_{n}^{(k)})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a time-homogeneous $(\mathcal{F}_{n+k})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$-markov chain. Is it true that $(X_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a time-homogeneous $(\mathcal{F}_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$-markov chain ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X_n$ be a non-backtracking random walk on the two-dimensional grid, that is $X_{n+1}$ is chosen uniformly at random among the neighbors of $X_n$ except $X_{n-1}$ (leaving three choices then).

Then $(X_{n-1},X_n)_n$ is Markov but $(X_n)_n$ is not.